# How can I find the IP of a NAS connected via SMB?

Tags: networking, ip, nas

The question says it all. I have a NAS which was working quite well for quite some time. For some or other reason I started using smb instead of ftp.

Now I can no longer access the configuration dashboard of the NAS. I am not sure what I messed up, but I do not know the IP address of the NAS anymore.

How can I find the IP address of the NAS?

Comment: Still looking for a nicer answer or something?

Comment: @Seth I was hoping geeMc would upgrade his answer. You're right let me accept an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a sophisticated or permanent solution, Bonjour protocol may fit, you can see its implementation in Linux Avahi. So you can point to your NAS as hostname.local or use Avahi Discover to get IP's and all services published in the network. (printers, ftp, smb, ssh...)

- Minimum installation for client side (your machine):

  ```
  sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon avahi-dnsconfd avahi-discover avahi-utils
  ```

  `avahi-dnsconfd` listens to the publishing and passes them to resolvconf. So you can point to the server as `nashostname.local`. as any other real public domain name. You can use it with http (firefox), samba share, ftp,...

  examples:

  ```
  $ ping salah-Aspire-5738.local

  PING salah-Aspire-5738.local (192.168.1.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from salah-Aspire-5738.local (192.168.1.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=6.09 ms

  $ nmap salah-Aspire-5738.local

  Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-01-30 15:31 CET
  Nmap scan report for salah-Aspire-5738.local (192.168.1.3)
  Host is up (0.066s latency).
  All 1000 scanned ports on salah-Aspire-5738.local (192.168.1.3) are closed

  Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.91 seconds
  ```

  `avahi-discover` & `avahi-utils`, GUI & CLI, are the user interact tool. They are optional in case you want to list all services published on the network.

  Avahi Discover showcase

  [image: Avahi Discover showcase]
- For NAS server side, if it is a Ubuntu base (Linux/BSD you can build source):

  ```
  sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon
  ```

  `avahi-daemon` provide services publishing.

  In case you are using Commercial NAS, many of them support service publishing using Bonjour.

See [Avahi (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29) or [its official website](http://avahi.org/).

Comment: I think you mean to say, "for NAS: avahi-discover". Then browse to your NAS in the popup window.

Comment: @don.joey, I meant the NAS server side, if it is a Ubuntu or Linux machine in general. The `avahi-daemon` provided publishing service. On client side (your machine), `avahi-dnsconfd` listens to the publishing and add passes them to `resolvconf`. So he can point to the server as nashostname.local. `avahi-discover` & `avahi-utils` are the user interact tool. Please, let me know if I missed anything or I wasn't clear enough. May be I should add that step on client side?

Comment: @don.joey , I've add examples and explain more. Sorry, I don't have any live real example. The figure show only default services "workstation" and "udisks"

Answer (score 2):

You could scan your network to see where it is up, e.g.

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24
```

where obviously you should change the network to your own. Then you'll get a list of devices which are up and running on current LAN.

To find your LAN IP you can use `ip addr`. If you are on WiFi the IP address will be near right to `inet` on something like `wlp2s0` network interface.

Comment: Excellent. Your answer would be even better if you'd explain how to find the ip address of one's own network.

Answer (score 0):

With the `arp` command you can scan the network. It helps in case you know there is a NAS but you don't know the name:

```
arp -a
```