# Is there a better way to connect to my NAS drive then smb://[IP address] with Lubuntu?

Tags: networking, lubuntu, samba, router, nas

I have lubuntu 14.04 installed, connected to a Virgin Broadband router, with a Seagate Media NAS drive also connected to the same router. Samba is installed.

From Windows 7 (on a different computer), I could simply browse the network and see Seagate-3A4AAA (not the real name) and double-click on it. But from my lubuntu desktop, browsing the network with PCManFM does not reveal any computers or the NAS drive, and typing `smb://Seagate-3A4AAA` doesn't work. However, what does work is typing the local IP address (discovered from the Windows 7 laptop) into PCManFM location like this `smb://192.168.0.4`. Presumably, rebooting the router or a power-cut could result in a different IP address being assigned. (Interestingly, we had a power-cut recently and the IP address hasn't changed).

Is there a better way of finding the drive and connecting to it without having to use a potentially changeable IP address? Is something wrong with my setup? Is it a router issue or a lubuntu issue?

Comment: Have you tried `smb://Seagate-3A4AAA.local/`? In case your NAS also uses Zeroconf/Avahi/Bonjour or whatever you want to call it, this should work. You may have to install the package `avahi-daemon`.

Comment: @the_Seppi no I haven't. I had no idea I needed a `.local` on the end. I will try that when I am at the computer tomorrow.

Comment: Zeroconf is implemented on basically any OS by default - except on Windows, which implements its own stuff - without `.local`

Comment: @the_Seppi makes sense now that I have googled zeroconf, hadn't heard of any of those terms before. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking . From this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/412580/how-can-i-find-the-ip-of-a-nas-connected-via-smb I guess I would install different avahi packages depending on what I want to do: just type in nasname.local, or find it by browsing the network?

Comment: It may already show up in your network; if it doesn't, try navigating to `smb://hostname.local/` manually.

Comment: @the_Seppi it works! I installed avahi-daemon with `sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon`. `smb://hostname.local` still didn't work so I rebooted. On logging back in, I tried typing it into PCManFM again and it worked. Thanks very much! Would you like to post it as an answer? I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows uses a different local DHCP-less communication protocol than, well, basically any other OS out there. Most other systems use implementations of the Zeroconf protocol: Bonjour on Apple systems, like Mac OS or iOS, and Avahi on Linux.

When using Zeroconf, hosts can be adressed with

```
hostname.local
```

If your NAS supports Zeroconf (simply try), you should be able to access it using the address

```
smb://Seagate-3A4AAA.local/
```

It may be that Avahi is not yet installed on your system. If so, install it using

```
sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon
```

If avahi-daemon does not start automatically, you can either reboot or start it manually with

```
sudo service avahi-daemon start
```